# Assign Fields programatically to custom node defined by custom module

Tags: entities

Trying to convert a module from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 which defines its own node type in hook_node_info.

Even though hook_node_info defines has_title and has_body to TRUE, how I can get these fields to appear on the node form? Previously, I used hook_form():

```
function mymodule_form(&$node, $form_state) { 
  $type = node_get_types('type', $node);

  if ($type->has_title) {
    $form['title'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => check_plain($type->title_label),
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#default_value' => $node->title,
        '#weight' => -25,
    );
  }

  if ($type->has_body) {
    $form['body_field'] = node_body_field($node, $type->body_label, $type->min_word_count);
    $form['body_field']['body']['#rows'] = 5;
    $form['body_field']['body']['#description'] = 'Enter a short message to present to the user.';
  }

  return $form;
}
```

In D6, this worked fine for me. In Drupal 7, hook_form has changed, and I am not quite following the documentation of it.

How can I utilize the Body and Title Field in core and assign them to this node type when the module is activated?

Furthermore, how can I define a new Field type to mimic Body (Long text with summary) to something of my choosing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add the body field to a content type, you use [node_add_body_field()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_add_body_field/7). To add a field that is not the body field, you use [field_create_field()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.crud.inc/function/field_create_field/7), if the field doesn't exist, and [field_create_instance()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.crud.inc/function/field_create_instance/7) to assign an instance of the field to an entity (e.g. a node or a user object).

As example of how to use those functions, you can look at [standard_install()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/profiles--standard--standard.install/function/standard_install/7), which is the installation hook of the standard profile, that contains the following code:

```
  $field = array(
    'field_name' => 'field_' . $vocabulary->machine_name, 
    'type' => 'taxonomy_term_reference',
    'cardinality' => FIELD_CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED, 
    'settings' => array(
      'allowed_values' => array(
        array(
          'vocabulary' => $vocabulary->machine_name, 
          'parent' => 0,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
  field_create_field($field);

  $instance = array(
    'field_name' => 'field_' . $vocabulary->machine_name, 
    'entity_type' => 'node', 
    'label' => 'Tags', 
    'bundle' => 'article', 
    'description' => $vocabulary->help, 
    'widget' => array(
      'type' => 'taxonomy_autocomplete', 
      'weight' => -4,
    ), 
    'display' => array(
      'default' => array(
        'type' => 'taxonomy_term_reference_link', 
        'weight' => 10,
      ), 
      'teaser' => array(
        'type' => 'taxonomy_term_reference_link', 
        'weight' => 10,
      ),
    ),
  );
  field_create_instance($instance);
```

The code is adding a taxonomy term field to the content type "Article."

Answer (score 1):

This is a great document on [Converting your module from Drupal 6.x to 7.x](http://drupal.org/update/modules/6/7)

In there is states

[node body field instances are now handled exclusively by field API](http://drupal.org/update/modules/6/7#body_field)

> When defining a node type or creating one with node_type_save(), the
>   'has_body' and 'body_label' keys have been deprecated.
>
> To add a body field, you can instead call node_add_body_field($type);
>   which will add the field instance to that node type. See blog.install
>   and forum.install for examples.

Check out [forum.install](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--forum--forum.install/function/forum_enable/7) & [blog.install](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--blog--blog.install/function/blog_install/7)

So the place where you want to do this is in mymodule.install,  and either inside the mymodule_install() or mymodule_enable().

Comment: also look at http://drupal.org/update/modules/6/7#body_teaser_fields

Comment: to mimic a field like the body, take the code from node_add_body_field and put in it a private function

Comment: There is no simple Field API to create and assign a field to a node type?

Comment: I don't think there is a simpler way, such as inside mymodule_form().  Drupal 7 uses fields instances, and from my understanding, they have to be added to the database before you can use them. Thats why the forum and blog module uses hook_install() & hook_enable().    Side Note: You can add them afterwards to the type using field_create_instance() & field_create_field() in a private function, but why would you.