# Possible to create fields without admin?

Tags: entities

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Assign Fields programatically to custom node defined by custom module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7142/assign-fields-programatically-to-custom-node-defined-by-custom-module)

Is it possible to create fields in code without using admin in Drupal 7?

Comment: Like this?
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7142/assign-fields-programatically-to-custom-node-defined-by-custom-module

Comment: sure check this link
[http://www.figover.com/node/15](http://www.figover.com/node/15)

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7142/assign-fields-programatically-to-custom-node-defined-by-custom-module - This is for custom node type module. My question is regarding a more general method for creating fields in code and modifying them without dealing with admin interface - e.g similar to Django models.

Comment: The code for a custom module is not different from the code you would use in other circumstances. The answers for that question already answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Since fieldable things in D7 are called "bundles", you essentially 1. create the field and 2. attach it to the bundle that uses it (could be a content type, etc.) I wrote this function to quickly create and attach fields in my module's .install file:

```
function _add_field_to_bundle($field_name, $cardinality, $type, $label, $entity_type, $bundle, $field_settings=array(), $instance_settings=array()) {

  $new_field = array(
    'field_name' => $field_name,
    'cardinality' => $cardinality,
    'type' => $type,
    'settings' => $field_settings,
  );
  field_create_field($new_field);


  $field_instance = array(
    'field_name' => $field_name,
    'label' => $label,
    'entity_type' => $entity_type,
    'bundle' => $bundle,
    'settings' => $instance_settings,
  );

  field_create_instance($field_instance);
}
```

To use this function to attach a thumbnail image field to a (node) content type:

```
_add_field_to_bundle('field_thumbnail', 1, 'image', 'Thumbnail', 'node', 'content_type');
```

Answer (score 0):

See The following functions.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.crud.inc/function/field_create_field/7
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.crud.inc/function/field_create_instance/7

There is an example here http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.crud.inc/function/field_create_field/7#comment-19499